# Android wear app does not run on a wearable device with no google play services installed

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I'm developing an android wear app for a wearable device which does not have Google Play Services installed on it (for China region). But the app fails to run with the following exception :

`Could not find wearable shared library classes. Please add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" /> to the application manifest`

I've already added this line in my manifest file, but it still throws the same exception. Below are my manifest and gradle files :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.abcd">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="false" />

        <!-- Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld app to run. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AbcActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**app: build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.abcd"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.5.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
}
```

I've made a lot of search regarding this, but i'm unable to find any appropriate solution which works.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Library `play-services-wearable:10.2.0` seems to be required for China;
but only when using [Fused Location Provider API or Data Layer API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating-app-china):

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0"
```

This is non-sense and should be removed:

```
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
```

And if this here fails:

```
<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
    android:required="false" />
```

The shared library is missing on-device, because it will only be known at compile-time:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'
```

I think you may eventually have to use `com.google.android.support` there:

```
implementation "com.android.support:wear:28.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.support:wearable:2.5.0"
compileOnly "com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0"
```

---

If the issue persists, consider filing an issue on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192711).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin. As you have mentioned, I've checked the device and yes the shared library is missing on-device. Also i do not have the rights to flash the OS with any other image, as it is a client provided device. So without flashing the device, can i still be able to run the app?

Comment: [Create Wear OS apps for China](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating-app-china) lists version `10.2.0` ...and I'm sure that it once was supported. But with the current `androidx` versions, this might not be supported anymore - or at least, it is not documented too well. `com.google.android.support:wearable:2.5.0` seems to be the last known-to-be-working version. For example: [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox/blob/master/wear/build.gradle).

Comment: I shall make the necessary changes in code and let you know the behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Even after doing the above mentioned code changes also i'm getting the below exception while launching app : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xyz.abcd/com.xyz.abcd.AbcActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find wearable shared library classes. Please add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" /> to the application manifest

Comment: @Jaydroid you could try `implementation "com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0"` ...but it might require it to be installed on the system partition and not inside an application. I mean, if you can run it on a wearable emulator, you can be certain that the ROM lacks that library... and flashing another ROM might be the only way to provide this library. Europe here, so I can only theorize.

Comment: I could build AOSP with Play Services for it, assuming that vendor binaries exist... but I'd assume that shipping me some sample device for testing might not be an option (and I couldn't read anything Chinese on-screen either). That stock ROM  is insufficient; but an emulator localized to Chinese should be able to run it.

Comment: As you said I'm able to run the app on an emulator(china version of android wear) which has 'com.google.android.wearable' pre-installed on system partition. But for the real device, i feel flashing ROM might be the only option.